# Printing a half pyramid from array elements

Tags: java, arrays, string, nested-loops

I'm pretty new to Java, just started learning it. I've got an array of numbers, with array length `origArraySize`:

```
29.50   10.80   16.40   87.80   12.20   63.70   13.90   25.00   77.40   97.40
```

I'm trying to arrange them in this format:

```
29.50
10.80   16.40
87.80   12.20   63.70
13.90   25.00   77.40   97.40
```

While I've seen similar half Pyramid questions, i just can't seem to figure out how to implement an array to print the numbers. Here's what I got so far, just a method of class rn:

```java
public String toString() {
    String t = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < this.origArraySize; i++) {
        t += String.format("%8.2f", array[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.println(t + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I know it includes nested for loops but I just can't seem to get it. The method `toString()` has to return `String` value, and I'm not sure how to implement that at the end either, but for now I tried with `t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not want an inner loop, you just need a couple of counters

```java
double arr[] = {29.50,10.80,16.40,87.80,12.20,63.70,13.90,25.00,77.40,97.40};

int loop = 0;
int printAtNum = 0;

for (double d : arr) {
    System.out.printf("%8.2f", d); // always print
    if (loop == printAtNum) {
        System.out.println(); // only print if loop is equal
                              // to incremented counter
        loop = 0;       // reset
        printAtNum++;   // increment
    } else {
        loop++;
    }
}
```

**output**

```
   29.50
   10.80   16.40
   87.80   12.20   63.70
   13.90   25.00   77.40   97.40
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two nested for loops. The internal action is to print and increment a single value:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] arr = {29.50,10.80,16.40,87.80,12.20,63.70,13.90,25.00,77.40,97.40};
    printHalfPyramid(arr);
}
```

```java
public static void printHalfPyramid(double[] arr) {
    int i = 0; // counter, index of an element in an array
    for (int row = 1; row < Integer.MAX_VALUE; row++) {
        for (int el = 0; el < row; el++) {
            // print a number and increment a counter
            System.out.print(arr[i++] + " ");
            // if the last element
            if (i == arr.length) return;
        }
        // line break, next row
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
29.5 
10.8 16.4 
87.8 12.2 63.7 
13.9 25.0 77.4 97.4
```